# XSLT disable-ouput-escaping not escaping character &lt;

Tags: html, xslt, xslt-1.0

In the following stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <h1>Music Collection:</h1>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Artist</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="catalog/cd/title" disable-output-escaping="yes" /></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="catalog/cd/artist" /></td>
      </tr>
    </table> 
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Why does it not convert the `&lt;` to `<` when used with the following HTML?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpy® -->
<catalog>
    <cd>
        <title>Empire Burlesque &lt; </title>
        <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>Columbia </company>
        <price>10.90</price>
        <year>1985</year>
    </cd>   
</catalog>
```

The output can be tested here.. http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=tryxsl_value-of

### Edit

Here is another example where it does not work

```
<xsl:for-each select="//productType"> 
<xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes" />
            <br></br>
</xsl:for-each>
```

With the DOE the < get stripped out. Without it i can see the < character (Using XSLT 1.0)

Comment: Your HTML is some (arbitrary?) XML, but definitely no HTML. Where can that output be seen? The XML provided in the example does not contain any &lt; in this title.

Comment: YOu can update the title to add the &lt;

Answer (score 2):

disable-output-encoding was an optional feature in XSLT 1 (and is deprecated in XSLT 2) so a processor is allowed to ignore it. In particular it is almost always ignored in any processing pipeline in which the output from XSLT is passed as an in-memory tree (a DOM node for example) to a following application which then serialises the XML. d-o-e is essentially a hint to the XSLT serialisation phase and in such a processing pipeline XSLT serialisation is not used.

Answer (score 1):

It is something processor-related (a bug I'd say) - using the .NET XSLT processor in Visual Studio I get `<` as expected, and I get `&lt;` if I remove `disable-output-escaping="yes"`

Answer (score 0):

The effect of disable-output-escaping depends on what processor you are using and on the way in which you are using it. You haven't given us enough information to answer these questions.

More pertinently, why are you using it? What problem are you trying to solve? Usually, when people use disable-output-escaping, they are going about things the wrong way - there's a better approach available. There are some cases where d-o-e is appropriate, but it means you can only use the stylesheet with a processor that supports it, in a pipeline where you know that the stylesheet's result tree is being piped straight into a serializer rather than into some other tree-consuming process.